# Parentheses instead of dashes: Is it required that the sentence will have the meaning with the "dashed" part omitted?

Tags: meaning, punctuation, programming, tech-writing

> #### Else If and Else after jump statements
>
> - Each guard must be a separate `If` with no `Else If` or `Else`.
> - Otherwise—i.e., when a jump statement belongs to “normal” code and not a guard—`Else If` and `Else` must be used regardless of its presence.

The meaning of the second list item is that `Else If` and `Else` must be used regardless of whether the jump statement exists or not.

If the reader will skip the part inside the dashes, the meaning will be lost:

> Otherwise, `Else If` and `Else` must be used regardless of its presence. **(The presence of *what*?)**

And this is why I use dashes and not parentheses. However, I'm still not sure whether it's correct.

Comment: Please Google `parenthetical phrase`.

Comment: As written, that's not the meaning of the second list item. Dashes and parentheses have exactly the same parenthetical meaning. The confusion remains the same regardless of which is used. Paired commas could also be used to the same effect. That essential information was put into a parenthetical statement (regardless of the symbols used) makes the sentence meaningless. It's grammatical, but it's semantically incorrect because *it* has no valid referent in the main text.

Comment: @JasonBassford Jason, thanks. That's an answer I looked for.